# All my screen comes back to the standard Ubuntu look, but I want my old Ubuntu Studio look

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS, 64 bit Linux.

Today I select ON the backports PPA, to have access to some specific software upgrades.

Everything was working so fine up... I restart the PC and I found... All the screen looks like the standard Ubuntu Gnome screen!

I had this screen desktop:

[image]

Now, I have this:

[image]

How can I revert this?

How can I get back to my old Ubuntu Studio desktop screen and menus?

Comment: At the time that you login, and enter your password, there is a little 'gear' icon next to the password field.  You can change the desktop there, from Gnome to Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! It worked!!! But... Just a doubt... Will I have to do this each time I start (or Power On) a new session in the PC?

Comment: gdm (sorry for earlier error, was led astray) should be your Display Manager which selects the default desktop at login unless you specify otherwise. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/gdm.8.html

Comment: @Juan It should remain at the environment you choose over reboots, unless a package install changes the setting.  I will type this up as an answer for you, if you would care to accept it.

Comment: Thanks to all of you!!! Now all it works so fine. BTW: There should be another way to set this (not at the login time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time that you login, and enter your password, there is a little 'gear' icon next to the password field. You can change the desktop there, from Gnome to Ubuntu.

The image below shows choices for Ubuntu, and Ubuntu on Wayland.  You installation may have different and/or more choices.

[image]

Comment: I have a PC where, because some reason, this session starting question panel doesn't appear... How can I get to see this panel?

Comment: @Juan Is your account set to auto-login?  I believe you can also get here by choosing to log yourself out (near the shutdown button) but you may need to remember your password.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it looks like you installed the "ubuntustudio-gnome-branding" package from the installer, which is not intended for users of the default Ubuntu Studio install. I recommend typing `sudo apt autoremove --purge ubuntustudio-gnome-branding` into a terminal window.

Comment: That didn't work in the PC I had the problem. I had to use Synaptic Package Manager to manually remove all the gnome desktop related apps and install all the xfce packages. Now, all is works so fine, but... I don't understand why in the other PCs I didn't have this issue. What could be different in this specific PC? ???

Comment: Installing the "ubuntustudio-gnome-branding" package adds the GNOME desktop and the gdm3 display manager since it's all a dependency of "gnome-session" which is a dependency of the branding package. It would have to have been done intentionally or accidentally, there's no other explanation.